# pdfbox 2.0 and subset font

Tags: java, pdfbox

We are using pdfbox 2.0 RC1 and we are trying to embed a font given by one of our customer. But once pdf is saved the file itself is very big so we are trying to embed only a subset of the used characters.

The code used is similar to the following:

```
public void setValue(PDTextField textbox, String value){
    PDFont currentFont = getFont();
    for (int index = 0; index < value.length();  ) {
        int codepoint = value.codePointAt(index);
        currentFont.addToSubset(codepoint);
        index += Character.charCount(codepoint);
    }
    textbox.setValue(value);
}
```

now, generated pdf is a lot smaller BUT the "writing" of the pdf is very slow.

Is there a way to know if given codepoint is already added ? Probably in this way I can speed up the generation.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe maintain a `Set<Integer>` of already added codepoints?

Comment: I don't want to keep a set of integers, because it is a job that is currently done by apache pdfbox. However, looking in source code I didn't found a way to know if a codepoint has been added or not.